# Multiple addresses (not LatLongs) in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

Ladies and gents,

**Long Version**

I have a database full of addresses which I need to plot on Google Maps, and embed within my webpage. The addresses are displayed textually, rather than LatLong, so:

"22 Sesame Street, Little Village, Little Town, AB1 9YZ"

And like I said, I have a number of these, and they all need plotting on one map.

I'm happy using jQuery/Javascript, PHP, XML, etc to do it.

I see a lot of sites doing this, seemingly easily, for example:

- [Yell.com](http://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=london&keywords=beauty%20salons&view=map&scrambleSeed=2046126515)

I don't, however, know whether Yell uses LatLongs to do it, or full addresses. Regardless, I only have the addresses to hand.

**Short Version**

Need to plot multiple, textual addresses in one Google Maps window, and embed it within my site.

**Disclaimer**

I've searched all over the web for over a week, unable to find a definitive answer. I did find what *might* have been classed as an answer (no, not possible), but I find this difficult to believe in this day in age, what with the things we can do with a site relatively easily, now.

Maybe I'm being optimistic...

Any help any of you can give would be absolutely golden, and much appreciated!

Thanks very much!

Dan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **geocode** your addresses, i.e. convert them into lat/lng coordinates, and then add them.

If you're already using Google, the obvious choice would be to use Google's geocoder.

You can either use the server-side [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), where, if you create an account and an API key, you can geocode addresses like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY
```

The returned JSON includes, among other things, an lat/lng. Use that to place it on your map.

Alternatively (and this is often a better solution), you can use the [client side javascript geocoder built into the javascript api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), in a manner similar to the following:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "Mountain View, CA"
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    // results contains multiple locations, ordered by estimated relevance
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

[This article](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client) provides a good example of the client side strategy you likely want to employ.

Comment: Thanks for replying! You'll have to excuse me, I'm not so well up on the APIs, so bodging my way through at the moment. So if I had 100 addresses, I'd have to throw each address at this link to get the LatLong, before plotting?

Comment: It depends slightly on what you want to do. If you've got a fixed set of addresses, I would simply use the server side geocoding (using that link and an api key) to get them geo-coded once and for all. If your addresses have a more dynamic nature, use the client side geocoder built into the geocoder api. That way, you don't run into rate limitations.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll have quite a lot of addresses, but not enough to run into limitations, I don't think. It's a relatively small website/business.

Comment: Remember that if you use client side geocoding, the rate limitations are per user, hence the recommendation from google to almost always use client side geocoding.

Comment: If you're just creating a one-off map of company addresses, you may be interested in using Google Fusion Tables. Add your addresses, geocode, and publish the map!